# WebAPI - Ajax POST Json call (Cross-domain) - Model-binder not working

Tags: jquery, json, cors, asp.net-web-api

On the Client-side:

```
var data = {Title":"Some Title","Description":"Something"} ;

$.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: apiUrl + "/Save",
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    success: function (returnedData) {},
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {},
    processData: false,
    async: false
});
```

On the Server-side:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(DataModel data)
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

        return null;
    }
```

This is the DataModel:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works correctly. However, when it makes a POST request to the "Save" controller-action, the properties on the Model is always null and not getting the values from the client-side.

Note that this is a cross-domain request to the "sub-domain" of my site (i.e. calling from example.com to api.example.com)

What I'm missing?

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Do other similar ajax requests work?

Comment: Thanks @KevinB, what shall I do instead? Btw, this will be run within Phonegap so I believe as long as it works on WebKit, it is fine.

Comment: Yes, in phonegap you do need that flag iirc.

Comment: Ah, i see something. `processData` is set to `false`, and `data` is an object, therefore it won't be sent. you should set processData to true, ***or(not and!)*** change the contentType to json and parse the object to json (depending on the requirements of your api)

Comment: I have tried processData to true; same issue. When I switched contentType to 'application/json' I get the 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present' error in Chrome..

Comment: hmm... i wouldn't have expected that change to break the CORS functionality... you coupled the contentType change with changing the data to a json string, right?

Comment: Yep, contentType : 'application/json' and dataType: 'json'

Comment: Changing the Content-Type of a CORS request to "application/json" may result in the browser sending a preflight request ahead of the intended request.  This would be true if the previous Content-Type was "text/plain", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", or "multipart/form-data".  In that case, you'll have to handle the OPTIONS (preflight) request server-side and acknowledge the Content-Type (and possibly the Accept) header(s) in your response.  You'll also need to acknowledge the origin in your preflight response, of course.

Comment: How do I make the preflight acknowledgement from the server? Many Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at enable-cors.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your ajax request with these options:

```
    contentType : 'application/json', dataType: 'json'.
```

After that, add this controller-method to your controller:

```
    [HttpOptions]
    public ActionResult Save()
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

        return null;
    }
```